# Bounds on CDF of a Transformation of Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, transformation

I am attempting to transform a random variable, but am having problems understanding over which range I need to integrate. The random variables in question are $X\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$ and $Y=e^{-X}$ My goal is to be able to get the CDF of $Y$

I have

\begin{align}
F_Y(y) & =P(Y\le y) \\
& =P(e^{-X}\le y) \\
& =P(-X\le \ln(y)) \\
& =P\left(X\ge \ln\left(\frac 1 y\right)\right)
\end{align}

I know furthermore that $x \in (0,1)$ and that $R_Y \in (\frac{1}{e}, 1)$.

If I understand correctly, I can obtain the CDF of $Y$ by some variation of $\int{F_X}\,dx$ which in this case is $\int1\,dx$ 
I feel like this should be an easy problem, 
but Ihave just not been able to understand the concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've just about finished the problem, and then you gave up when you were three feet below the summit.

If $1/e \le y \le 1$ then 
$$
F_Y(y) = \Pr(e^{-X} \le y) =  \Pr(X\ge - \ln y) = 1-(-\ln y).
$$

So
$$F_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 1 +\ln y &\text{if }& \frac 1 e \le y\le 1, \\[6pt]
1 &\text{if }& 1< y, \\[6pt]
0 &\text{if }& y< \tfrac 1e.  \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.
Just note that $$P(X \ge \ln(1/y)) = 1 - \ln(1/y) = 1 + \ln y$$
because $X$ is uniform on $(0,1)$.